# How to delete or destruct an instance of a data structure or a record?

Tags: .net, data-structures, record, null, delphi-prism

I have a data structure as follows.

```
TJustCalGroup = record
    SigName,GroupName:string;
    RawMin,RawMax:LongInt;
end;
```

I create an instance of the record or data structure as follows.

```
var ARecord := new TJustCalGroup;
```

Then, I want to delete the instance or mark it as being unused. So, I am doing the following.

```
ARecord := Nil;
```

However, it is not working. It keeps raising an error, "Can not assign nil to TJustCalGroup."

So, then how do you make it nil or null or free up its memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delphi prism (or Oxygene)record is equivalent to a [Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) , the structs (or records) are value types and is allocated always on the stack (even when you uses the new operator), so you don't need free the memory.

Comment: RRUZ, Won't that lead to memory leak over time? Since, you are only adding to the stack and never removed.

Comment: No, the records are value types, so no memory leak is generated, every time which you uses the New operator no memory is allocated, instead only the members of the record are inializated to his default values.